# Instance state not being preserved using InstanceContextMode.PerSession

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm building a WCF application and I need to preserve the instance state of the service between sessions.
My service implementation looks like this:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class Service : IService {
    private int i;

    public int Increment() {
        return i++;
    }
}
```

I need to preserve the value of the i variable between each session. However, `InstanceContextMode.PerSession` seems to be doing the same thing as `InstanceContextMode.PerCall`. 
So if call `Increment()` a couple of times in the client application I get 0 every time:

```
var serviceClient = new ServiceClient();
MessageBox.Show(serviceClient.Increment()); // 0
MessageBox.Show(serviceClient.Increment()); // 0
```

I tested the same thing using `InstanceContextMode.Single` and it works as expected but this behavior does not suit my needs because the instance state of the service cannot be preserved between clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to go out on a whim and assume you are using `BasicHttpBinding`.

`BasicHttpBinding` does not support sessions due to the connectionless nature of HTTP. Any binding that does not support reliable sessions or if the `ReliableSession` property of the binding is set to false, then the service will behave as **PerCall**.

You can view which bindings support reliable sessions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731092.aspx) and you can view the details into `InstanceContextMode` [here](http://dotnetmentors.com/wcf/instance-management-using-instancecontextmode-property-in-wcf.aspx).

Comment: Indeed I'm using BasicHttpBinding. But that's my only option because according to my searches, IIS doesn't support other bindings. Thank you for your help.